# Function not able render notes in JSX column

Tags: arrays, reactjs, jsx

I am making a simple drag and drop task app and would like to understand how I can render the notes in the column that I have by calling a function that is mapping over a notes array and returning the JSX `<Note/>` element.

Here is the column:

```
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleOnDragEnd}>
    <Column
    dropId={uuidv4()}
    text="To-Do"
      showNotes={displayNotes()}
    />
```

And here is the function mapping over the notes Array:

```
function displayNotes() {
notes.map((note, index) => {
  return (
    <Note key={index} id={uuidv4()} noteContent={note} index={index} />
  );
});
```

}

This was working when I would place the map method directly in showNotes props in `<Column/>`. But as soon as I separate the map method into its own function and call it in the showNotes props in `<Column/>`, the functionality fails to render the notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you forget return for function?

```
function displayNotes() {
 return notes.map((note, index) => {
  return (
    <Note key={index} id={uuidv4()} noteContent={note} index={index} />
  );
})
};
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks for the assist.